# complex column selection in dplyr group_by

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to use, *within a `group_by` call*, dplyr's column selectors like `starts_with()`, `ends_with()`, `matches()`, ..., or even the syntax `-colName`.

(Silly) example of the syntax I am after:

```
library("dplyr")

# I would like to do something like this
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(matches("a")) %>%
   summarise(mpg=mean(mpg))
# but I get a "wrong result size" error
```

I was hoping it would work, by analogy with:

```
mtcars %>% select(matches("a"))
```

which here would select columns `drat, am, gear, carb`

To be crystal clear: I want to use `matches("a")` (or equivalent) to achieve the same output as:

```
mtcars %>% 
group_by(drat, am, gear, carb) %>%
summarise(mpg=mean(mpg))
```

I am only interested in answers using dplyr. Thanks!

---

The current answer, while good, only allows selecting columns with a regex.

I am still looking for a more global answer that would allow the use of the full range of dplyr's selection syntax.  Of course I can massage any regex to select what I want, but I wish I had something which integrates nicer with dplyr (especially to use the `-colName` syntax). I am going to leave this opened for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group_by_at` was added to dplyr some time in 2017 and does just that.

```
mtcars %>% 
   group_by_at(matches("a")) %>%
   summarise(mpg=mean(mpg))
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an option to construct your own `group_at()` which I don't think exists with the `matches` and SE  `group_by_()` function:

```
mtcars %>% 
      group_by_(.dots = names(mtcars)[matches("a", vars = names(mtcars))]) %>%
      summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))

#Source: local data frame [26 x 5]
#Groups: drat, am, gear [?]

#    drat    am  gear  carb   mpg
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   2.76     0     3     1 18.10
#2   2.76     0     3     2 15.50
#3   2.93     0     3     4 10.40
#4   3.00     0     3     4 10.40
#5   3.07     0     3     3 16.30
#6   3.08     0     3     1 21.40
#7   3.08     0     3     2 19.20
#8   3.15     0     3     2 16.95
#9   3.21     0     3     4 14.30
#10  3.23     0     3     4 14.70
# ... with 16 more rows
```

Or equivalently, just use `grep`:

```
mtcars %>% 
      group_by_(.dots = grep('a', names(mtcars), value = TRUE)) %>%
      summarise(mpg=mean(mpg))
```

Comment: You can avoid the double call to the names with `grep("a", names(mtcars), val=TRUE)`

Comment: @PierreLafortune Right. Forget about that.

Comment: Many thanks to both, I am adding this to my handy functions! `group_at <- function(df, pattern)  group_by_(df, .dots=grep(names(df), pattern=pattern, value=T))`